# How to refresh HttpWebResponse from c# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I built a program that connects to asp site (Login.aspx), and takes some text from the htmp response.

Now I want to make a button that refreshes the html and checks if there any changes in the site.

I use HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse.

How can I do it?
Thanks!

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ?

Comment: I saved the response and request to data members, the first time I log in the streamreader reat the response, but the second time it throws exception "Stream was not readable.".  The main issue: response = (HttpWebResponse)this.hwrRequest.GetResponse();
            this.hwrResponse = response;
            sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());